# Why should filename set to sockaddr_un::sun_path[0] be offset by 1?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm learning about socket programming. The following code is based on an example which intends to demonstrate the basics of socket connection.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

#define ASSERT( EXPRESSION ) \
{ \
  if ( ! ( EXPRESSION ) ) \
  { \
    std::ostringstream oss; \
    oss << "Expression \"" << #EXPRESSION << "\" failed at line " << __LINE__ \
        << "; errno == " << errno << " (" << strerror( errno ) << ")"; \
    throw std::runtime_error( oss.str() ); \
  } \
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  int ret_val = 0;
  int sd;
  char socket_pathname[ L_tmpnam ];

  try
  {
    errno = 0;

    // Create a socket
    sd = socket( AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    ASSERT( sd >= 0 );

    ASSERT( NULL != tmpnam( socket_pathname ) );
    ASSERT( strlen( socket_pathname ) < sizeof( ((struct sockaddr_un*)0)->sun_path ) - 1 );

    // Create socaddr_un, "derived class" of sockaddr.
    struct sockaddr_un su;
    su.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
    strncpy( su.sun_path + 1, socket_pathname, sizeof( su.sun_path ) );
    su.sun_path[ 0 ] = 'Z';

    int su_len = SUN_LEN( &su );
    su.sun_path[0] = '\0';      // Why???

    // bind address to socket.
    int result = bind( sd, (struct sockaddr*)&su, su_len );
    ASSERT( -1 != result );

    std::cout << "Socket pathname: " << socket_pathname << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Socket pathname2: " << su.sun_path + 1 << std::endl;

    system( "netstat -pa --unix 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/Active UNIX/,/^Proto/p;/a.out/p'" );
  }
  catch( std::runtime_error& e )
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    ret_val = 1;
  }

  if ( sd >= 0 ) close( sd );
  remove( socket_pathname );

  return ret_val;
}
```

I don't understand why the filename set in `sockaddr_un::sun_path` needs to be offset by 1. It's a curious convention, and neither the example from which I'm learning nor other reading material explained the purpose behind this. Can someone explain?

Also, prior to calling `SUN_LEN()`, if I set `sockaddr_un::sun_path[0]` to `\0`, the resulting pathname associated with my socket seems to be an incrementing number prefixed with `"@"`, e.g. `@00017`, `@00018`, etc. It seems `sockaddr_un::sun_path[0]` must be some ASCII value other than 0 - why is this? Is it expected to be any specific value? If I change it to other non-NULL values, it has no observable effect on the program behavior.

Comment: Because su.sun_path + 1 then I believe the count to strncpy() must be sizeof( su.sun_path - 1) or a long socket_pathname will corrupt the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the following Linux manpage:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html

> The `AF_UNIX` (also known as `AF_LOCAL`) socket family is used to communicate between processes on the same machine efficiently. Traditionally, UNIX domain sockets can be either unnamed, or **bound to a filesystem pathname** (marked as being of type socket).  **Linux also supports an abstract namespace which is independent of the filesystem.**
>
> ...
>
> Three types of address are distinguished in the `sockaddr_un` structure:
>
> - *pathname*: a UNIX domain socket can be bound to a null-terminated filesystem pathname using `bind(2)`.  When the address of a pathname socket is returned (by one of the system calls noted above), its length is `offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + strlen(sun_path) + 1` and **`sun_path` contains the null-terminated pathname**.  (On Linux, the above `offsetof()` expression equates to the same value as `sizeof(sa_family_t)`, but some other implementations include other fields before `sun_path`, so the `offsetof()` expression more portably describes the size of the address structure.)
>
>   For further details of pathname sockets, see below.
> - *unnamed*: A stream socket that has not been bound to a pathname using `bind(2)` has no name.  Likewise, the two sockets created by `socketpair(2)` are unnamed.  When the address of an unnamed socket is returned, its length is `sizeof(sa_family_t)`, and `sun_path` should not be inspected.
> - *abstract*: **an abstract socket address is distinguished (from a pathname socket) by the fact that `sun_path[0]` is a null byte ('\0')**.  The socket's address in this namespace is given by the additional bytes in `sun_path` that are covered by the specified length of the address structure.  (Null bytes in the name have no special significance.)  The name has no connection with filesystem pathnames.  When the address of an abstract socket is returned, the returned `addrlen` is greater than `sizeof(sa_family_t)` (i.e., greater than 2), and the name of the socket is contained in the first `(addrlen - sizeof(sa_family_t))` bytes of `sun_path`.

So, `sun_path[0]` is used to differentiate between a bound pathname socket address and an abstract socket address.  If `sun_path[0]` is 0, the address is abstract.  Otherwise, the entire `sun_path` (including `sun_path[0]`) is a filesystem path.